# Sql - count by other column value not id with join

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two `tag_group` and `tag` tables bound by a foreign key and wrote an sql query with Postgres 14.

`tag_group` table:

| id | slug |
| --- | --- |
| 6 | awesome-team |

`tag` table:

| id | team_id | name | tag_group_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | Tag 1 | 6 |
| 2 | 3 | Tag 2 | 6 |

I want to count all tags from `tag` table that belong to specific `tag_group`.
I managed to do so with:

```
SELECT count(*) AS total_count FROM tag
JOIN tag_group tg
ON tg.id = tag_group_id   
WHERE tag_group_id = 6 AND tg.team_id = 3;
```

I got confused of how can I do the same operation but with the exception that instead of having and **ID** as parameter I have only **slug** instead.. Can I still retrieve results if I have only **slug** *value* from `tag_group` table ?

Comment: `SELECT count(*) AS total_count FROM tag
JOIN tag_group tg
ON tg.id = tag_group_id   
WHERE tg.slug = 'awesome-team'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you can query by slug too you just need to change you query like this

```
SELECT count(*) AS total_count FROM tag
JOIN tag_group tg
ON tg.id = tag.tag_group_id   
WHERE tag.slug = 'slug' AND tg.team_id = 3;
```

as you can see i change the join condition like this

```
ON tg.id = tag.tag_group_id
```

it means join all record by the id

but in the query where condition i change query like this

```
WHERE tag.slug = 'slug' AND tg.team_id = 3;
```

now you can filter your result by slug

Comment: Cool, thanks! But I want to point out by slug in tag_group table not in tag table. I see that you are pointing to the slug in tag table? @AryanHasanzadeh

Comment: @FilipStojavonic i'm sorry this is typing mistake you need to change tag.slug = 'slug' to tg.slug = 'slug'